# Use a NodeJS session in PHP

Tags: php, node.js, express, session

I'm completely new to using PHP and NodeJS together. Is it possible to use a NodeJS session in PHP?

Already tried searching, but it seems like people only ask about using a PHP session in NodeJS. But I want to do the opposite.

```
let ses = req.session;
ses.userid = result[0].ID;
ses.admin = result[0].Admin;
ses.email = result[0].Email;
ses.name = result[0].Name;
ses.denyarticle = result[0].DenyArticle;
ses.denyarticlecomment = result[0].DenyArticleComment;
```

This is how I currently set my session in NodeJS using express-session.

Comment: If you're using `express-session`, then you can set the session store to something other than the default MemoryStore so it saves the session data in a database from which you can read the session data in your PHP code.

Comment: Okay, how can I do that? And how do I then know which session belongs to the current user in php?

Comment: Official docs would be a good place to start (https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/master/README.md#session-store-implementation)

Comment: Thank you. I know have my sessions stored in my database, but my question is still unanswered. How can I now associate a sessionid with the user, so that I can use the session in PHP?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but each session sets a unique identifier in a cookie which can be read in PHP and can be used to look up the data for that particular session from the database.

Comment: Is there a specific name for that cookie or is it somewhere defined inside my nodejs script?

Comment: It's right there in the docs (https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/master/README.md#name). The default name is `connect.sid`

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: You're welcome :)